# Are there SQL statements on SQL Server 2016 that will not get rolled back?

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2016, rollback

I am studying for my cert exam 70-761.

Running a practice test, a question I ran across, asked: "What statements will not get rolled back within a transaction?"

When I check my answers afterward I was surprised to see "ALTER" and "UPDATE" where the right answers.

However, in testing this theory, I have not had any statements NOT rollback when an error was introduced.

In case it makes a difference, I am running SQL Server Express based on SQL Server 2016 (v13).

Is this an error in the practice question key?

Here is a copy of the transaction.

```
    begin
        begin try
            begin tran

                update t4 
                set name = 'mikeyshit' 
                where name = 'Jim';

                drop table t4;
                drop table t5;

                create table t4
                (
                    id uniqueidentifier primary key default NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
                    name nvarchar(50)
                );

                insert into t4 (name) 
                values ('Jim'), ('Keith'), ('Paula'), ('Rose');

                create table t5
                (
                    id uniqueidentifier primary key default NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
                    name nvarchar(50)
                );

                insert into t5 (name) 
                values ('Jimmy'), ('Will'), ('Willow'), ('Lydia'), ('Bob');

                -- test of rollback violates PK
                insert into t1 (col1, col2) values (21, 'Chill');

            commit tran
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            Rollback Tran
            select
                ERROR_NUMBER(),
                ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
                ERROR_STATE(),
                ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                ERROR_LINE()
        END CATCH
    end
```

Comment: I would expect modifications to get rolled back (including UPDATE and ALTER), with the exception of modifications to table variables.

Comment: Tested this theory.   Yes.. The table variable did NOT rollback.  Thanks!